# RXJS subscribe completion pattern

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I found myself using the following pattern in Typescript and RXJS:

```
httpCall() : Observable<string> {...}

// set loading = true
httpCall.subscribe(
    (p) => { 
        // do stuff;
    }, 
    (error)=> {
        // display error
        // set loading = false
    }, 
    () => {
        // set loading = false
    });
```

Is there any way to prevent the double calling of `// set loading = false` ?

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: Look at `finally` (if you're using patching operators) or `finalize` (if you're using pipeable operators).

Comment: @Cartant - Would the block be inside  try{}finally{} block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cartant's suggestion is good, but you can also solve this by refactoring to an improved design.

```
const stopLoading = () => {
  this.loading = false;
};

const error = (error: any) => {
  // display error
  stopLoading();
};

const next = value => { ... };

httpCall.subscribe({next, error, complete: stopLoading});
```

**NOTE:**

Because I am a curmudgeon, I will note, as I have done numerous times, that using Observables to represent HTTP Requests, is bad design on Angular's part and makes life needlessly complicated. They only return one value and that makes them an ugly mismatch for Observables 90% of the time.

It also deprives us of the lovely `async`/`await` feature, thrusting us back into callback hell.

This pisses me off.

Here is what I would do:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export default class {
  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      this.data = await httpCall().toPromise(); 
    } 
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    finally {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Strongly consider this, it is 10x simpler than RxJS code for a 90% of HTTP scenarios and the maintainability advantages should be very clear to anyone reading this.

Comment: I totally agree with you on this specific modest requirement, but pipe-ing your HTTP response through several operators in a complex scenario will create async/await hell. RxJS and Async/Await can definitely work together. Instead of choosing one or the other, learn how to use both based on your needs. Good luck!

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu absolutely learn both, if for no other reason than to learn. Rx is something a competent programmer should be able to learn. However, I think it is easier to learn when the use case is clear cut.  it's also worth noting that `flatMap` and other observable functions work with promise returning projections, so you can definitely mix and match.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'do' operator for that

```
httpCall.do((data) => {
// Do smth
}).subscribe...
```

Comment: actually `tap` if you refer to the modern rxjs (if one can call it modern of course :D)

Comment: Its a nice idea but won't work because the OP only wants it to be called on either termination event. This will call it for each value emitted and _not_ for terminals

Comment: Ah, finally a use case for [materialize](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-materialize)!

Comment: httpCall.materialize().do(x => { if (x.kind === 'E' || x.kind === 'C') // do smth }).dematerialize().subscribe

Comment: BTW more about materialize in my video course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video